# If $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}(f(x)\cdot y)=0\space\forall y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, show that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, vector-spaces

> Let $f(x):\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a function such that
>   $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}(f(x)\cdot y)=0\space\forall y\in\mathbb{R}^n$$
>   Show that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=\vec{0}$.

Since the limit is zero, we have the equality

$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}(f(x)\cdot y)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}|f(x)\cdot y|=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\|f(x)\|\|y\|cos(\theta_x)$

Then, one can conclude that $\|f(x)\|\rightarrow0$ or $cos(\theta_x)\rightarrow0$.

If the case is the first one, we are done, otherwise, $cos(\theta_x)\rightarrow0$ and then $f(x)$ approaches to a vector that is orthogonal to every $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, so it must be zero, but I don't know how to prove it. Thaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying $f(x) \to 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the same as saying all the components of $f$ tends to $0$. Take $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ to be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and then apply the hypothesis.